# Powershell Currency formatting

Tags: powershell

Why does this work

```
"{0:C2}" -f 123456.789
```

Returns-  $123,456.79

But if I have a variable consisting of numbers, it won't format?

```
"{0:C2}" -f $deposits
```

$deposits is a variable obtained from parsing an XML file.

Confused.  Thanks for your help

Comment: The number is a string.  Try : "{0:C2}" -f [double]::Parse($deposits)

Comment: Spot on jdweng. Thank you for your time!